# split paragraphs in array php

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array of this form:

```
 $steps = array (0=> "the sentence one. the sentence two. the sentence three.",
            1=> "the sentence for. the sentence 5");
```

and I want to have an array `$steps` like this:

```
 $steps = array (0 => "the sentence one.",
            1 => "the sentence two.",
             .
             .
             4 =>"the sentence for."
             );
```

I tried to use `explode` and `implode` but I did not succeed.

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?
What doesn't work with your code and where is it?

Comment: What if there is a short for something in the sentence? Example `clean floors, walls and etc. and make sure it shines` that is one sentence with a dot in it.

Comment: What about question mark like in `Must this sentence be splitted? And this one 123.45 with float number in it? Sentence 3.`

Comment: Also, should we expect the sentences to follow grammar rules i.e. capital letters after dot?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split your strings in your existing array using `(?<=\.\s)(?=\w)` regex and then iterate over all the matches using `foreach` loop and keep adding all the splitted strings in an array. Check this PHP code,

```
$steps = array (0=> "the sentence one. the sentence two. the sentence three.",
        1=> "the sentence for. the sentence 5");
$arr = array();
foreach ($steps as $s) {
    $mat = preg_split('/(?<=\.\s)(?=\w)/', $s);
    foreach($mat as $m) {
        array_push($arr,$m);
    }
}
print_r($arr);
```

Prints,

```
Array
(
    [0] => the sentence one. 
    [1] => the sentence two. 
    [2] => the sentence three.
    [3] => the sentence for. 
    [4] => the sentence 5
)
```

This assumes that a new sentence starts after a dot `.` is followed by a space by looking at your current sample data. In case you have more complicated sample data containing dots in various forms, please post your such samples and if need be, my solution can be updated to accommodate them as well.

Comment: Does using `@` before a string even do anything? Just curious (I didn't downvote).

Comment: @Jeto: Use of `@` was not really intentional. Let me remove it.

Comment: @Downvoter: Your downvote came exactly after 6 second I posted my answer. Posted answer time: 18:15:40 and Downvote time: 18:15:46. Clearly you didn't even go through my answer and downvoted it. Can you enlighten me with your cause? Hopefully I will gain some valuable advice from you.

Comment: Most likely it's because the question is unclear. Some will police SO and downvote those who answer borderline questions

Comment: Just my two cents since I got notified for this: some people immediately downvote questions where askers didn't show any effort. I kinda agree that's it may encourage them to ask more similar low effort questions in the future. People should add a comment when downvoting though, I wish SO would enforce this.  Anyway, take my upvote!

Comment: @Andreas: I agree that could be a cause. But everyone can perceive a question differently. I feel OP has an array of simple sentences which he wants to split and combine all to get a single array containing all sentences. Although there might be corner cases but I don't think it is necessary that, 1. OP has that and 2. Even if OP has, he may clarify further. Moreover even the post has only one downvote and I've seen so many posts where despite multiple downvotes, posts as well as answers solves the purpose. Many thanks for replying. I appreciate truly.

Comment: @Jeto: Thanks for the upvote and yes you could be right with that reason. Although I would salute people who downvote as well as leave some message so at least I get some context of the downvote of my answer. When they don't leave any message, it just leaves me puzzled whether I wrote a bad answer or missed something in my answer. I really appreciate you considering and taking time to stop by and reply.

Comment: Just to be clear, I did not downvote, that was just my guess

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if this works for you `preg_split("/\. (?=[A-Z])/", join(" ", $steps));`

Your target array :

```
$steps = array (
    0 => "The sentence one. The sentence two. The sentence three.",
    1 => "The sentence for. The sentence 5"
);

$steps_unified = preg_split("/\. (?=[A-Z])/", join(" ", $steps));

print_r ($steps_unified);
```

You will get:

```
Array ( 
    [0] => The sentence one 
    [1] => The sentence two 
    [2] => The sentence three 
    [3] => The sentence for 
    [4] => The sentence 5 
)
```

If we use proper grammar, lines should end with a '.' and begin with a space and a Capital latter word.

Comment: @Andreas What if there is a short for something in the sentence? Example clean floors, walls and etc. and make sure it shines that is one sentence with a dot in it. I hope my answers satisfies your concern. Sorry if it does not!